# Excel INDIRECT function gives #N/A, WHY?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following excel formula:

```
=CORREL(INDIRECT("Raw0!"&COL_LETTER(Raw0!B$795)&MATCH("z";Raw!$B1:$B795;0)&":"&COL_LETTER(Raw0!B$795)&CELL("row";Raw0!B795));INDIRECT(COL_LETTER($B797)&MATCH("z";Raw!$B5:$B795;0)+ROW(B7)-1&":"&CELL("address";$B797)))
```

It looks complicated but the idea is rather simple, I want to define 2 arrays with INDIRECT functions in order to calculate cross-correlation between the arrays, i.e.:
=CORREL(array1;array2).

The above formula always gives me #N/A, i.e. excel error message "not available".
However, if I put the arguments of the two INDIRECT functions above in a couple of cells, let's say C803 and C804, and the I use the formula

```
=CORREL(INDIRECT(C803);INDIRECT(C804))
```

it works fine.

How is it possible? as cells C803 and C804 contains exactly the same writings I used in the first function above, i.e.:
C803 contains

```
="Raw0!"&COL_LETTER(Raw0!B$795)&MATCH("z";Raw!$B1:$B795;0)&":"&COL_LETTER(Raw0!B$795)&CELL("row";Raw0!B795)
```

and C804 contains

```
=COL_LETTER($B797)&MATCH("z";Raw!$B5:$B795;0)+ROW(B7)-1&":"&CELL("address";$B797)
```

*Note: COL_LETTER() is a simple VBA function I created that returns the letter of the column of the cell argument. It works fine, I tested it.*

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: A side note, but do you know that `INDIRECT` is volatile, and you may be able to do this with the non-volatile `INDEX`?

Comment: What is the COL_LETTER?  Can you show that code

Comment: @Scott Sorry, COL_LETTER is a VBA function I created just to convert column number to the column letter. I will modify the question to clarify this.

Comment: I believe, depending on what `COL_LETTER` does you can use: `INDEX(Raw0!B:B;MATCH("z";Raw!$B1:$B795;0)):INDEX(Raw0!B:B;ROW(B795))`

Comment: Are you on O365?  Simplifying and debugging formulas using the LET() function is life-changing.  If not, you need to start with something `= CELL("address";$B797)` and start building your formula with one additional step each time.  At sone point you’ll get a value you weren’t expecting.

Comment: @Max unfortunately no. I am using O2019 professional